# how to access folder present in git repository using url

Tags: git

I made a folder in git repository and placed html and css file in it. but im not able to access that folder using url of that folder. so that html web page can be shown.

https://parvinder85.github.io/Module1/assingment1

Actually I want to access the above address. Where "parvinder85" is my user name, "Module1" is a repository name, and "assingment1" is the folder in which I placed two files(HTML, CSS). I pushed these files from the local server to repository using git commands. In those files, I wrote some code for a website that has to be shown if I'll be able to access that link.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what your question is. But if you want to access the contents of a github repository from an external script, you can use :

```
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/githubusername/repositoryname/branch(master for example)/folder/file
```

If you want to set up a github page, all the information are here
https://pages.github.com/

> Click on the Settings tab and scroll down to the GitHub Pages section.
> Then select the master branch source and click on the Save button.

(You need to have your `index.html` file at the repository root)